# How To Customise Implicit Not Found Message

Tags: scala

I would like to replace the standard implicit not found message when using the `=:=` operator in the following example:

```scala
sealed trait TBoolean
sealed trait TTrue extends TBoolean
sealed trait TFalse extends TBoolean

class Builder[X <: TBoolean, Y <: TBoolean, Z <: TBoolean] private(x: Int, y: Int, z: List[List[Int]]) {
  protected def this() = this(-1, -1, List.empty)

  def withX(xx: Int)(implicit ev: X =:= TFalse) = new Builder[TTrue, Y, Z](xx, this.y, this.z)

  def withY(yy: Int)(implicit ev: Y =:= TFalse) = new Builder[X, TTrue, Z](this.x, yy, this.z)

  def withZ(zz: List[List[Int]])(implicit ev: Z =:= TFalse) = new Builder[X, Y, TTrue](this.x, this.y, zz)

  def build()(implicit ev1: Y =:= TTrue, ev2: X =:= TTrue, ev3: Z =:= TTrue) = println(s"${x} ${y} ${z}")
}

object Builder {
  def apply() = new Builder[TFalse, TFalse, TFalse]
}
```

If I try to build an illegal object like this:

```scala
Builder().withX(1).withY(1).withZ(List.empty).withY(1).build   // i.e. two withY calls
```

I get the usual:

```scala
error: Cannot prove that TTrue =:= TFalse.
```

I would like to customise this message so that it is more informative.  I tried using `@scala.annotation.implicitNotFound("custom message: blah")` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where are you putting the annotation?

Comment: I tried putting it on the `with..` methods and the `build` method but to no effect

Comment: Since this is the failing code, it would be a good idea to put this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `implicitNotFound` annotation Scaladoc (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/annotation/implicitNotFound.html) :

> ... cannot be found, annotate **the class** C with @implicitNotFound.

So, in case of using `=:=` class, which has this anotation, you can not override it, unless you will implement own type equality prove type class, with your own error message:

```
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Custom type equals prove message ${From} =::= ${To}.")
    sealed abstract class =::=[From, To]
    private final val singleton_=::= = new =::=[Any,Any] {}
    object =::= {
      implicit def tpEquals[A]: A =::= A = singleton_=::=.asInstanceOf[A =::= A]
    }
```

and use it:

```
def withZ(zz: List[List[Int]])(implicit ev: Z =::= TFalse)
```

So the result error message will be:

```
Custom type equals prove message TTrue =::= TFalse.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You could change it for a particular method by inlining annotation like so

```
def g[A](i: A)(implicit @implicitNotFound("You should not be a ${A}") ev: A =:= Int) = ???

g("") // Error: You should not be a String
```

but of course that will work for just that method.

Comment: Does it work for you? I've tried this approach but still getting `Cannot prove that String =:= Int` error message. I'm using Scala 2.12 with `-Xlint:implicit-not-found` Scalac option. Could you share your environment settings, please? Thanks

Comment: @IvanKurchenko Seems to work on my machine, Scala 2.13.1. I do not have any special flags set.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, I think worth it to mention that this going to work only for Scala 2.13, because I've checked on both 2.12 and 2.13 this approach. Thank you again for sharing this!